# Networking Dilemma IP stack(Microcontrollers)

Tags: networking, microcontroller

I basically have used the ethernet connection successfully with Microcontrollers to control real world aspects,The dilemma is of IP address I mean how can 192.168.0.155 be accessed from around the world without any specific MAC ID attached to it, I wanted to implement the same networking usage with a GSM module eliinating wires but that doesn't have MAC addressing so TCP connection from it towards a IP client won't reach?

Comment: Have a look at [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

Comment: You could use http://dyn.com/dns/. Your device will advertise his Public IP to it and then you'll be able to reach it. (with a few adjustments of course)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you did your 'real world control' with Ethernet before, but the MAC address does not 'live' past the next recipient (which means after the next switch) so do not use it for anything.

Your 192.168.x.x address is private, so it will never appear beyond your internet gateway (i.e. your GSM modem if you used GPRS), and it cannot be used directly for anything on the internet. It is not easy to briefly explain here how the internet routing works, but you should either use port forwarding towards your private IP address given to you by hour DHCP server (in which you have to initiate request from the client so that other side would not the IP address and the port), or you have to either have fixed public IP address or you could use some dynamic DNS service (like http://www.noip.com/), or you can update data from the client on some server over which you have control (like if you updated data manually from your PC).

All summed up, it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve, but I would say you need to check out some things about internet routing before you proceed.